# Dynamic Memory Allocation - Keep seg faulting

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to dynamically allocate memory using these two functions but I keep getting a segfault. The code takes in strings from a file. I need to dynamically allocate memory for a specific number of monsters using structs, pointers and malloc.

```
typedef struct monster {
  char *name; 
  char *element; 
  int population;
  } monster;

monster* createMonster(char *name, char *element, int population){


//Copying the data into the monster
  monster *temp =(monster*) malloc(sizeof(monster));
  strcpy(temp->name, name);
  strcpy(temp->element, element);
  strcpy(temp->population, population);
  return temp; 
  free(temp);
}

 
monster** readMonsters(FILE* infile, int *monsterCount){

//getting monster count and creating temp pointers
monster **temp = NULL;
char m_word [8];
fscanf(infile, "%d", monsterCount); 
fscanf(infile, "%s", m_word); //reading the word monster to skip it
char*  temp_name;
char* temp_element;
int temp_pop; 

//allocating memory and creating an array of monster pointers * mcount
temp = (monster**)malloc(*monsterCount * sizeof(monster*));
for(int i = 0; i < monsterCount; i++){

  fscanf(infile, "%s",temp_name); 
  fscanf(infile, "%s",temp_element); 
  fscanf(infile, "%d",temp_pop); 
  monster *monster_temp = createMonster(temp_name, temp_element, temp_pop);
  temp[i]->name = monster_temp->name; 
  temp[i]->element = monster_temp->element; 
  temp[i]->population = monster_temp->population; 
}

  
 return temp; 
}
```

Comment: Please change `strcpy(temp->population, population);` to `temp->population = population;` because an integer is not a string.

Comment: The `scanf` statements will go wrong, either because there is no memory allocated for `%s` entries, or because the `%d` data entry needs a pointer, such as `fscanf(infile, "%d", &temp_pop);` note the added `&` and please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: There are more errors the compiler should be telling you, such as `i < monsterCount;` which should be `i < *monsterCount;`

Comment: In addition to all of the above, the three assignments starting with `temp[i]->member = ....` should be replaced with a single `temp[i] = monster_temp;` . And fyi, the `free(temp);` in `createMonster` is unreachable, unnecessary, and ultimately incorrect anyway. It should be removed. What reference guide are you learning C from, because might I suggest you find an alternative.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `temp = (monster**)malloc(*monsterCount * sizeof(monster*));`  1) the returned type, in C, is `void*` which cn be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fscanf(infile, "%d", monsterCount);` and other calls to the `scanf()` family of functions:    1) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input array to avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  These functions return the number of successful input format conversions ( or EOF )

Comment: regarding statements like: `char*  temp_name;
 char*  temp_element;`  these only declare a pointer, NOT where that pointer points.  Therefore,  statements like: `fscanf(infile, "%s",temp_name); 
  fscanf(infile, "%s",temp_element);` are placing the data into some random place in memory.  This is a great way to cause a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `monster *temp = malloc(sizeof(monster));
 strcpy(temp->name, name);
 strcpy(temp->element, element);`   these copy one random location in memory to another random location.  An excellent way to cause a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the definition of struct monster.

If struct monster contains a lot of char* and you are assigning a char* to it, that char* needs to be allocated somewhere.  It doesn't look like temp_name and temp_element have been allocated, which would cause a crash on the scanf.

Comment: typedef struct monster {
  char *name; 
  char *element; 
  int population;
  } monster;

Answer (score 1):

your code segfault because you write at uninitialized and unallocated pointers

you directly write with strcpy *name* and *element* field of your struct but these two field point at unknow location

also, you try strcpy an integer, directly assign it : *temp->population = population ;*

finally you cannot *return temp* and *free temp*, if you return it it will be reused, you must not free it, hopefully the free is never reach as you exit the function one line before :)

for storing your strings into the struct, you have some possibilities

- declare them as array of char in your structure : char name[64]
- use a buffer in your structure and set the name and element field point on part of it
- malloc them with strlen of original strings before the copy
- directly point name and element vars of your createMonster function to the pointer, it will use original memory, but it's not suitable here as they come from temporary memory

an example of create monster function using a static common buffer for your strings (untested) :

```
#define MONSTER_MAX_BF 64

typedef struct monster {
  char *name; 
  char *element; 
  int population;
  char bf[MONSTER_MAX_BF];
} monster;

monster* createMonster(char *name, char *element, int population){
  monster *temp =(monster*) malloc(sizeof(monster));
  char * lastBf = temp->bf + (MONSTER_MAX_BF - 1); // buffer last char
  char *bfp = bf, *p ;

  // copy name
  temp->name = bfp ;
  p = name ;
  while( *p && *bfp != lastBf ) *bfp++ = *p++ ;
  *bfp++ = 0;

  // copy element
  temp->element = bfp ;
  p = element ;
  while( *p && *bfp != lastBf ) *bfp++ = *p++ ;
  *bfp = 0;
  
  temp->population = population ;

  return temp; 
}
```